# getting an error on running a powershell command

Tags: excel, xml, powershell

I am getting this following error:

```
exception calling "UploadString" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (500) 
Internal Server Error." At C:\Cinegy_Type\Helpers-Type.ps1:146 char:5 + $web.UploadString($url, 
$xmlDoc.OuterXml) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], 
MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

The method is this:

```
function Type-UpdateVariable([string]$name, [string]$value, [string]$type = "Text", [string]$server="localhost", [int]$instance=0)
{
    #make a Type PostRequest XML document using .Net XML document object
    $xmlDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument;

    #add root element for request - which is a 'PostRequest' element
    $xmlRootElem =  $xmlDoc.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement('PostRequest'));

    #create SetValue element and define variable Name, Type and Value
    $xmlSetValueElem = $xmlRootElem.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement('SetValue'));
    $xmlSetValueElem.SetAttribute("Name", $name);
    $xmlSetValueElem.SetAttribute("Type",$type);
    $xmlSetValueElem.SetAttribute("Value", $value);

    #create a .Net webclient which will be used to perform the HTTP POST
    $web = new-object net.webclient

    #Air requires that the data is in XML format and declared properly - so add the HTTP Header to state this
    $web.Headers.add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")

    #perform the actual HTTP post to the IP and port (which is 5521 + instance number) of the XML data
    $url = "http://" + $server + ":" + (5521 + $instance) + "/postbox"
    $web.UploadString($url, $xmlDoc.OuterXml)
}
```

Line 146 is:
 `$web.UploadString($url, $xmlDoc.OuterXml)`

what I do not understand is that this was working yesterday.

The full code can be found here: (Do not use line number here for reference, this has 3 scripts.)

https://pastebin.com/RtisgmiB

Comment: This uses excel and populates a display on a video after converting the information in the excel file.

Comment: Check the error.log on the server. It could be that the upload is exceeding the `MaxRequestLen` value?

Answer (score 0):

The web server you're posting to is having a problem; [see meaning of a HTTP status code 500](https://httpstatuses.com/). Unless the data passed to your function are problematic, your code looks fine. There is nothing you're missing in that Powershell error message, which would give you a clue as to the issue.

1. Check the error log on the web server (best option)
2. Output the parameters to the console with the purpose of submitting the request manually through Postman, cURL, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Adam, ill try that and let you know